# Getting values from another table on Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays

I'm kind of new on Ruby on Rails and I have a little problem: 
I have three classes (upgrade, credit_card and user), and, as a User, I need to insert my credit cards to buy an upgrade. All my classes are working properly. But the problem is that I need to get all the credit cards numbers that the user had already inserted and put them into the Upgrade.form (using a select box or anything else) as an array, so one of them can be selected. So, I wanted to bring all the credit cards information to one variable:

```
    class Upgrade < ActiveRecord::Base
      attr_accessible :account_plan, :credit_card
      has_one :credit_card
      belongs_to :user

      CREDIT_CARD_GETTER = current_user.credit_card
    end
```

Then, I want to to use this on my select box. On the form page:

```
   <div class="field">
    <%= f.label "Choose your Credit Card*" %><br />
    <%= f.select :credit_card, #<%= current_user.credit_card.number %> %>
```

What should I do? Is it right? Sorry I'm a newbie on ruby.
Thanks!

**UPDATE**

For helping, I'm updating the codes, and put them all here. I want to show the Credit Card Number as an option.

UPGRADE index
        My Account Plans:
        
        
        Plano de Compra

```
    <% @upgrades.each do |upgrade| %>
    <tr>
    <td><%= upgrade.account_plan %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', upgrade, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
    </tr>
    <% end %>
    </table>

    <br />
```

Upgrade Model

```
    class Upgrade < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessible :account_plan, :credit_card
    belongs_to :user 
    has_many :credit_cards
    end
```

User Model

```
    class User < ActiveRecord::Base        
    has_many :credit_cards
    has_many :upgrades
```

Credit Card form

```
    <div class="field">
    <%= f.label "Flag" %><br />
    <%= f.select :flag,   [['American Express', '1'],['VISA', '2'],['Dinners', '3'],   ['MasterCard', '4']] %>
    </div><br>
    <div class="field">
    <%= f.label "Nome no Cartão" %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :name, :class => "span3"%>
    </div>
    <div class="field">
    <%= f.label "Card Number" %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :number, :class => "span3"%>
    </div>
    <div class="field">
    <%= f.label "Data de Validade" %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :date %>
    </div>
    <div class="field">
    <%= f.label "Sec. Code" %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :seg_cod, :class => "span1"%>
    </div>
    <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
    </div>
    <% end %>
```

Credit Card Model

```
    class CreditCard < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessible :date, :flag, :name, :number, :seg_cod
    validates_presence_of :date, :flag, :name, :number, :seg_cod, presence => true
    belongs_to :upgrade
    belongs_to :user
    end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose that `user has_many credit_cards`. So I think you should

1st: Change attr_accessible in Upgrade

```
attr_accessible :account_plan, :credit_card_id
```

2nd. Remove or change logic for this line

```
CREDIT_CARD_GETTER = current_user.credit_card
```

because `CREDIT_CARD_GETTER` is a constant and you change it for each users?! I can't catch for what aim. Maybe it should be just removed or moved somewhere

3rd. in select on the form you should write smth like this

```
<%= f.select(:credit_card_id, current_user.credt_cards.map{ |card| [card.number, card.id] }) %>
```

4th. (very important!) In controller you must check that entered credit card really belogns to current user

```
def create
  redirect_to some_path if current_user.credit_card_ids.exclude?(params[:upgrade][:credit_card_id])
  # create upgrade here
end
```

Comment: Thank you, it helped me, but I'm still having problems with the f.select, and I'm not using a :credit_card_id, just :credit_card. I've updated the codes.

Comment: ups did not pay attention on it. Are you sure that `has_many :credit_cards` for Upgrade is correct? Maybe user can create a new Upgrade paying only one of his credit_card?

Comment: I do not know your business logic but I think `has_one` is incorrect too. For example User has one credit card. He creates one Upgrade, lately he wants to upgrade to another plan using the same card. But he can't do it because `credit_cards.upgrade_id` has already occupied. How can you create a new Upgrade and connect it to the same credit_card? It seems to me Upgrade should `belongs_to` credit_card. If I am not right and your references are logical then you have two choises: `accept_nested_attributes_for` or setup value manually in controller.

Comment: It makes sense, I haven't thought about that. I think it should work, thanks. But now one last question, what about the syntax to bring the information? Just an for exemple,     <f.select :credit:card, ['<%= current_user.credit_card.number','0']]. What do you suggest?

Comment: see 3rd point in the answer. You should understand that `f.select...` it is already Rails [form helper](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormBuilder.html#method-i-select) so this code must be in `<%= ... %>`

Answer (score 0):

I think to pass variables to views you can use instance variables like this:

```
@Credits = current_user.credit_card
```

then you can access @Credits from views.

Comment: or perhaps a clever pun

Answer (score 0):

Change this

```
<%= f.select :credit_card, .... %>
```

to this

```
<select_tag name="user[credit_card]">
 <option_tag value="">None</option>
 <option value="1">David</option>
 <option value="2" selected="selected">Sam</option>
 <option value="3">Tobias</option>
</select>
```

but your value must be valid for the user credit card.

Answer (score 0):

If the User class `has_many credit_cards`, you can simply call `current_user.credit_cards` to bring up the ActiveRecord Relation object containing that user's cards.

A couple of things to note: first, you shouldn't define the `CREDIT_CARD_GETTER` constant. It may throw errors (constants in Ruby are picky if you try dynamically defining them) and, equally importantly, it is not accessible outside of the class unless you define a method that calls it. Assuming you have `current_user` defined in your ApplicationController, you don't need constants -- you don't even need to pass in in an instance variable -- current_user will be available in any views, so `current_user.credit_cards` will still do what you need.

Second, just from a security standpoint, you shouldn't be storing the user's credit card data. It's a huge security risk. Instead, I would suggest two safer options. One: encrypt the credit cards using something like [BCrypt](http://rubygems.org/gems/bcrypt-ruby) so that the `credit_cards` table has two columns, a string `obscured_card` (with values like "************1234") and a string `card_hash`, which is some the encrypted version of the card. Two, if you don't want to handle encryption yourself or don't want to worry about the security risks, use a payment gem like [Stripe](https://stripe.com/) to handle your payments for you.

Comment: Thanks for the security tips! It's just a school project, so I don't need exactly to worry about this, but it's a great tip once again! Thank you very much